# Selecting boolean expressions

Tags: select, plsql, coding-style, hql, boolean-expression

In MySQL I can select a boolean expression like this:

```
select (foo > bar and some = thing) as myFlag
...
```

But in other SQL dialects (in my case: Oracle PL/SQL and Hibernate HQL) it doesn't work.

The only workaround I found is this:

```
select case when (foo > bar and some = thing) then true else false end as myFlag
...
```

which I find quite ugly.

Is there a better way to write such expressions?

Answer (score 0):

Better is a very subjective term. However, CASE statements are the only way I know of to bring this type of logic into an Oracle SQL statement. There is a BOOLEAN datatype in PL/SQL, however, so if that is really what you are using the following would work. No need to do a context switch by using SQL in your block.

```
DECLARE
   my_bool BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
   my_bool := 1 > 2;
END;
/
```